# Selenium selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException error sending text to an element within iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

im new to python and recently got into selenium , i made small projects for linkedin or twitter with it from a tutorial but now i wanted to do smth for my work(finance) and my problem is:

On this website: https://mfinante.gov.ro/domenii/informatii-contribuabili/persoane-juridice/info-pj-selectie-dupa-cui

When i try to find a element by any selector(name xpath css selectors etc) it tells me there is no such element

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

URL = 'https://mfinante.gov.ro/domenii/informatii-contribuabili/persoane-juridice/info-pj-selectie-dupa-cui'


s = Service('My chromedriver path')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s)

driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
cui_entry = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.col-sm-4 p input')
cui_entry.send_keys('23484xxx')
```

What i want it to do is to write this code where it says **Introduceti codul unic de identificare (numeric):** but it seems like im doing something wrong

Comment: element you are trying to access is inside a frame. You need to switch to the frame and do sendkeys();

Answer (score 0):

To send a character sequence to the *Enter the unique identification code (numeric)* field as the elements are within an [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://mfinante.gov.ro/domenii/informatii-contribuabili/persoane-juridice/info-pj-selectie-dupa-cui")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#_com_liferay_iframe_web_portlet_IFramePortlet_INSTANCE_AAFALwmoH3eD_iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='cod']"))).send_keys("23484")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://mfinante.gov.ro/domenii/informatii-contribuabili/persoane-juridice/info-pj-selectie-dupa-cui")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='_com_liferay_iframe_web_portlet_IFramePortlet_INSTANCE_AAFALwmoH3eD_iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='cod']"))).send_keys("23484")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: mfinante]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)